# Unity EventHandler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to c# and unity, and want to use EventHandler to announce other script for doing something.

Some code have been subscribed to this event.

What "if(RefreshLevel != null)" is actually do, what is the content of "RefreshLevel", and why this event is not triggered?

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
  public static GameLevel current;

  private void Awake()
  {
    current = this;
  }

  private int level = 1;

  private int manyItem;
  private int burnedItem = 0;

  public event EventHandler<LevelEventArgs> RefreshLevel;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    itemWorld = GameObject.Find("ItemWorld");
    manyItem = itemWorld.transform.childCount;
  }

  public void LevelUp()
  {
    burnedItem += 1;

    if (burnedItem < manyItem)
    {
      level += 1;

      if(RefreshLevel != null)
      {
        RefreshLevel(this, new LevelEventArgs(level));
      }

      Debug.Log("Burned Item: " + burnedItem);
      Debug.Log("Level: " + level);
    }
    else if(burnedItem == manyItem)
    {
      Debug.Log("Burned Item: " + burnedItem);
      Debug.Log("Ghost Dead");
    }
  }
}

public class LevelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public LevelEventArgs(int level)
  {
    Level = level;
  }

  public int Level;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
if(RefreshLevel != null)
```

does nothing else than checking if there is anyone "listening" to that event. As long as nobody attached a listener/callback to the event (the invocation list is empty) it is equal to `null` and invoking it would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

You can also write it as

```
RefreshLevel?.Invoke(this, new LevelEventArgs(level));
```

which is a) shorter to write and b) makes clearer that this is an event and not a normal method.

---

#### Background

[`EventHandler<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler)

> public delegate void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);

is just a [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates), meaning a template for a method signature (similar to an interface for classes)

Then the script is using it as an [`event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) which has a special meaning

> Events are a special kind of multicast delegate that can only be invoked from within the class or struct where they are declared (the publisher class). If other classes or structs subscribe to the event, their event handler methods will be called when the publisher class raises the event. For more information and code examples, see Events and Delegates.

And behind it there is a [`MulticastDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate)

> Represents a multicast delegate; that is, a delegate that can have more than one element in its invocation list.

That "invocation list" are the registered callbacks.

And finally there is the [operator `MulticastDelegate.Inequality`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate.op_inequality#System_MulticastDelegate_op_Inequality_System_MulticastDelegate_System_MulticastDelegate_) which returns

> true if d1 and d2 do not have the same invocation lists; otherwise, false

And

> Two delegates are equal if they are **not `null`** and are of exactly the same type, their invocation lists contain the same number of elements, and every element in the invocation list of the first delegate is equal to the corresponding element in the invocation list of the second delegate.

So if you compare an `event` to `null` it is true, as long as there are no elements in the invocation list.

---

#### Further notes

> Some code have been subscribed to this event.

Allow me to claim that this is **not true**. If your event is never invoked (but your other conditions met) it means you nowhere have registered any callbacks to the event like e.g.

```
private void Start()
{
    yourGameLevel.RefreshLevel += OnGameLevelRefreshed;
}

private void OnGameLevelRefreshed(object sender, LevelEventArgs args)
{
    ...
}
```

or it could simply mean that the `GameLevel` instance you registered the callbacks for is not the same as the one you are looking at.

If this is able to change (assuming that due to the `GameLevel.current` thing) you might want to rather make your event `static` since you anyway pass in the reference for the sender in case someone needs it.

```
public static event EventHandler<LevelEventArgs> RefreshLevel;
```

and then rather go

```
private void Start()
{
    GameLevel.RefreshLevel += OnGameLevelRefreshed;
}

private void OnGameLevelRefreshed(object sender, LevelEventArgs args)
{
    ...
}
```

this way you can be sure that even if the current instance is changed/destroyed you are still receiving any of the invoked events.

Answer (score -1):

if RefreshLevel != null, that means someone has subscribed to the event.
if RefreshLevel == null, that means no one has subscribed to the event.

Comment: This is what the other answer said yesterday.